# How to select certain field dynamically in Scala \ Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am not sure if the title describes my problem accurately but here is my problem:

`dump` is of type:

```
dump: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String, String)]
```

for example:

```
val dump = sc.parallelize(List(("a","b","c","s")))
```

and I have the following for-loop:

```
   for (i <- List(0,1,2,3)) {
      val temp = dump.map(x=> x._i)
    }
```

But IntelliJ indicates there is an error in `x._i`. Any ideas?

Comment: What type is `dump`? What are you trying to do with with `_i`? Please  edit your question and provide a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, because it's pretty much impossible to work out what you mean now http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you have an indexed sequence of four elements of the same type, you really want to be using a List or Vector. Tuples are used for aggregating a number of things that may be dissimilar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ is correct in pointing out that you are using an incorrect syntax.

What you are trying to do, can be achieved using something like:

```
for (i <- List(0, 1, 2, 3)) {
  val temp = dump.map(x => x.productElement(i))
}
```

[Tuples](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2) are actual instances of a class, and they are not exactly an array that you can access using an index. Also, scala, unlike some other languages like JavaScript, doesn't allow string based property access (unless you want to use reflection). What you are trying could work, with some syntactical changes, in a languages like JS but not in Scala.

However, at least in this case, the same thing can be achieved using the `productElement` method call as each all Tuples are also instances of [Product](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product), which does have the facilities to iterate over the elements, or access them via indices. Note that index of 0 equals `._1`, and so on.

Also, with reference to the comment by @Archeg, there is a limit to what you can put into tuples. There are tuple classes ranging from [Tuple1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple1) to [Tuple22](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple22). Which means that tuples can contain, at most, 22 elements.

Comment: Also it's probably worth mentioning that Scala has restriction on the amount of elements you can put in `Tuple` I think it's 22, I'm not sure. Tuples are not designed to be used in this way